# What is the IUPAC name of borax?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

Please don't say sodium tetraborate decahydrate since that is not the real composition of borax.

Borax contains tetranuclear coordination complexes $\ce{[B4O5(OH)4]^-^2}$. I'm asking about the name of this complex in borax.

Comment: *Sodium tetraborate decahydrate* is a legitimate IUPAC name. If you want to impress a girl, use **sodium bicyclo[3.3.1]tetraboroxane-3,7-diolate hydrate (2:1:10)**, or pick further German/French names from [here](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.17339255.html?rid=e2a3475c-a6b5-4015-9285-d768c5f375ff).

Comment: This might help you-https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59273/structure-of-borax

Answer (score 6):

The name suggested [here](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.17339255.html?rid=e2a3475c-a6b5-4015-9285-d768c5f375ff) (via the question comments), the anion-corresponding part, ‘bicyclo[3.3.1]tetraboroxane-3,7-diolate’ ($\ce{[B4O5(O)2]^2-}$) obviously does not match with the tetraborate formula $\ce{[B4O5(OH)4]^2-}$ present in [borax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borax), whose structure, confirmed by X-ray crystallography, including hydrogens<sup>[1]</sup>, is

[image: Fig.1 Tetraborate anion]

However, the ‘bicyclo[3.3.1]tetraboroxane’ part is correct, for the parent hydride:

[image: Fig.2 Bicyclotetraboroxane]

This type of names is known e.g. for the ‘cyclotriboroxane’ name for [boroxine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boroxine), or ‘cyclotetrasiloxane’ (in [octamethylcyclotetrasiloxane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octamethylcyclotetrasiloxane)).

So the name would be rather 1,3,5,7-tetrahydroxybicyclo[3.3.1]tetraboroxane, or bicyclo[3.3.1]tetraboroxane-1,3,5,7-tetrol, however it still does not explicitly tell that it's an anion.

Interestingly, this boroxane, siloxane type names (interchanging element/oxygen pattern) is rather marginally mentioned in the inorganic nomenclature, notably more detailed in the organic nomenclature.<sup>[2]</sup>

**Inorganic additive nomenclature** is able to constructs names for similar skeletons,<sup>[3]</sup> but somewhat differently than organic nomenclature.

E.g. bicyclo[*x*.*y*.*z*]*N*ane (where *N* is the numerical prefix root, with the exception for 1..4, ‘meth’..‘but’, for the organic names) would be named: *N*carby-[0*a*.*z*<sup>1,*b*</sup>]dicycle, where *a* = *x*+*y*+2 and *b* = *x*+2. If the structure is an ion, it's ‘…cyclate’ followed by the charge in parentheses. One advantage is that the first numeral is the size of the (largest) cycle, not just a branch.

Some examples from the book:

> [image: Example 1]
>
> 1,7-diazyundecasulfy-[012.1<sup>1,7</sup>]dicycle
> *(IR-1.5.3.4 Example 6)*
>
> [image: Example 2]
>
> *cyclo*-triphosporic acid
> 2,4,6-trihydroxido-2,4,6-trioxido-1,3,5-trioxy-2,4,6-triphosphy-[6]cycle
> *(IR-8.3 Example 5)*
>
> [image: Example 3]
>
> tetraaluminy-1-lithy-[05.0<sup>1,3</sup>0<sup>1,4</sup>0<sup>2,5</sup>]tetracyclate(1−)
> *(IR-7.4.3 Example 11)*

*(The leading zero in the first numeral in the square brackets is intentional for the cycles, however in the latter example, it's not used, despite IR-7.4.2 *Nodal descriptor*, example 3, that states that the nodal descriptor for hexacycle is ‘06’.)*

With this nomenclature we can get very descriptive (but almost unusable) names
**1,3,5,7-tetrahydroxido-1,3,5,7-tetrabory-2,4,6,8,9-pentaoxy-[08.1<sup>1,5</sup>]dicyclate(2−)**,
1,3,5,7-tetrahydroxidotetrabory-2,4,6,8,9-pentaoxy-[08.1<sup>1,5</sup>]dicyclate(2−), or
1,3,5,7-tetrahydroxido-1,3,5,7-tetraborypentaoxy-[08.1<sup>1,5</sup>]dicyclate(2−).

References:

1. Levy H.A., Lisensky G.C. [Crystal structures of sodium sulfate decahydrate (Glauber's salt) and sodium tetraborate decahydrate (borax). Redetermination by neutron diffraction](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740878011504) *Acta Crystallographica Section B* 34 (1978): p. 3507
2. [IUPAC Blue Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_Blue_Book) 2013, P-52.1.6.2
3. [IUPAC Red Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_Red_Book) 2005, IR-7.4 Additive nomenclature: Inorganic chains and rings

Comment: *snort* dicyclate! :D Yep, that almost unusable, indeed...